# Safari css rotate issue with bxslider

Tags: jquery, css, safari, bxslider, rotatetransform

I have made `bxSlider` with css rotation of 360 degrees. This is working fine in all browsers except in Safari.

Can anyone help me with this? Please find link **[here](http://jsbin.com/goqedu/1/edit?html,css,output)**.  Code below:

```
    $('#TestimonialUL').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    mode: 'fade',
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        $('#TestimonialUL > li').eq(0).addClass('active-slide');
    },
    onSlideNext: function (){
        $('#TestimonialUL').css({
            'transition': 'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s',
            '-o-transition': 'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s',
            '-moz-transition': 'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s',
            '-webkit-transition': 'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s', 
            '-moz-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
            '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
            'backface-visibility': 'hidden',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(-360deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(-360deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(-360deg)',
            'transform': 'rotateY(-360deg)'
        }); 

        $('.client-innerBG .bx-viewport').css({
            '-o-perspective': '800px',
            '-moz-perspective': '800px',
            '-webkit-perspective': '800px',
            'perspective': '800px',
            '-webkit-transform-origin': 'top left',
            'transform-origin': 'top left',
            '-webkit-transform-style': 'preserve-3D',
            'transform-style': 'preserve-3D'
        });     

    },  
    onSlidePrev: function (){
        $('#TestimonialUL').css({
            '-o-transition':'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s',
            '-moz-transition':'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s',
            '-webkit-transition':'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s',
            'transition':'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s', 
            '-webkit-backface-visibility':'hidden',
            'backface-visibility':'hidden',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(360deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(360deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(360deg)',
            'transform': 'rotateY(360deg)'
        }); 
        $('.client-innerBG .bx-viewport').css({
            '-o-perspective': '800px',
            '-moz-perspective': '800px',
            '-webkit-perspective': '800px',
            'perspective': '800px',
            '-webkit-transform-origin': 'top left',
            'transform-origin': 'top left',
            '-webkit-transform-style': 'preserve-3D',
            'transform-style': 'preserve-3D'
        }); 

    },
    onSlideAfter: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
        //console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
        $('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
        $('#TestimonialUL > li').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject).addClass('active-slide');

        $('#TestimonialUL').css({
            'transition':'0',
            '-o-transition':'0',
            '-moz-transition':'0',
            '-webkit-transition':'0', 
            '-moz-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
            '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
            'backface-visibility': 'hidden',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(0deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(0deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(0deg)',
            'transform': 'rotateY(0deg)'
        });
        $('.client-innerBG .bx-viewport').attr('style','');

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you blackbishop for editing question. I'm new to stockoverflow. It was good learning form you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the CSS rule `-webkit-transition` you need to reference the transform rule. In the case of webkit you need to reference the `-webkit-transform` rule rather than the `transform` rule.

So `'-webkit-transition': 'transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s'` will need to be `'-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0s'`.

Take care, you may also need to do the same with the `-moz` prefixed rule to target older versions of firefox better.